# Pre-populate Form Field With The Internal Millisecond Clock From Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, forms, unix-timestamp, auto-populate

I have a form on my website that I need to pre-populate with the current unix millisecond timestamp.

I do have another form field (in the same form) which successfully pre-populates the Date (Month, Day, Year) with the following code:

```
 <div>DATE<br><input name="date" id="date"></div>

 <script>
 (function() {
 var days = ['','','','','','',''];
 var months =
['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','June','July','Aug','Sept','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
Date.prototype.getMonthName = function() {
return months[ this.getMonth() ]; };
Date.prototype.getDayName = function() {
return days[ this.getDay() ]; }; })();
var now = new Date();
var day = now.getDayName();
var month = now.getMonthName();
document.getElementById('date').value = day + ' ' + month + ' ' + 
now.getDate() + ', ' + now.getFullYear();
</script>
```

However... I'm not having the same luck when attempting to pre-populate a second form field with the Unix Millisecond timestamp using this code:

```
 <div>TIMESTAMP URL<br><input name="timeStampURL" id="timeStampURL"></div>

 <script>
 var d = new Date();
 document.getElementById('timeStampURL').innerHTML = d.getTime();
 </script>
```

I don't understand why the two codes behave differently that way, but any advice as to how to get that script to pre-populate the field would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input elements don't have any content, so setting their *innerHTML* property does nothing. Your first function is setting the *value* attribute, so should your second:

```js
function showTimeValue() {
  document.getElementById('timeValue').value = Date.now();
}

window.onload = showTimeValue;
```

```html
<input id="timeValue">
<button onclick="showTimeValue()">Update time value</button>
```

Each time you run the code, you'll get an updated value.

Comment: Thank you Rob. Much appreciated!

Comment: Can I use the same button as the 'submit' button for my form?

Comment: @JamieSexton—yes, but be aware that forms can be submitted without clicking the submit button, so likely better to put a submit listener on the form that updates the field when the form is submitted.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I don't know how to do that. But I did it this way and used some CSS to hide the 'update' button behind the 'submit' button. So far, it seems to work fine and does update the timeValue on the other side. Is that not a good way?  <div class="buttonWrapper">
<button class="refreshButton" onclick="showTimeValue()">
<input class="submitButton" type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT"></button>
</div>

Comment: @JamieSexton—you can't put markup inside a button, the input will be moved outside the button. Also, naming it "submit" means you can't call the form's submit method (because *form.submit* now references the input, not the method). A button element in a form is a submit button by default.